# Removing the navigation bar without getting rid of color Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am programming an app in Swift 2 on XCode 7.3 for iOS 9.3, and I have a search controller which is part of a navigation controller. I want to hide the navigation bar for this specific view, but when I do the background color of the status bar becomes white on the very top of the screen, and I want to keep it colored. Is there a way to do so while also hiding the navigation bar?
Here's an image for reference: [Search View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK6Id.png)

Comment: You want to place the search bar on the place of navigationBar?

Answer (score 0):

self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

```
self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
```

Answer (score 0):

for hide status bar for particuler scrren:

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .None)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None)
}
```

for navigation embeded with search controller use below code:

```
 self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
```

Answer (score 0):

The background color of the status bar becomes white on the very top of the screen and NavigationBar is Hide at that time solution is add one sub view with background color in ViewController's viewDidLoad method. Add following code in ViewController's viewDidLoad method.

```
let viewStatusBarBG = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 20))
        viewStatusBarBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.89, green: 0.22, blue: 0.37, alpha: 1.0)
        self.view.addSubview(viewStatusBarBG)
```

Set backgroundColor whatever you want.